# How to change the value of a variable that is declared out of a function?

Tags: function, variables, rstudio, overwrite

Let's say you've a variable called "ENV.myvar" in your code. Then you've have written a function, "myfun", that has some goal and return an object (for example an array). ENV.myvar is used for computation and for some reason it has been modified during the process.

```
ENV.myvar <- 0;
myfun <- function(in1,in2,...,inN){

#declaring the output object
fun.myarray <- c(0,0,0);

#some code
...
#here ENV.myvar is modified for some reason
ENV.myvar = ENV.myvar + 20;

#code that works on fun.myarray
...
#return the object
fun.myarray
}
```

Finally we get to the point of the question: the function returns only the object but should overwrite permanently an external variable used during the process. Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, even though it's not recommended, because it's not the expected behaviour of a function to change anything outside its environment. Still, this is how you could do it:

```
myvar <- 0
myf <- function() {
  assign("myvar", 10, envir = parent.env(environment()))
  return("Value of 'myvar' changed to 10 in parent environment")
}
myf()
myvar
# [1] 10
```

You can change the `parent.env(environment())` part to get a specific environment, or just `.GlobalEnv`, depending on the call stack and your needs.